# How to delete empty rows in SQL while getting data from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I need to get last 50 tags from database, there will be more empty rows in database, I need to delete that empty rows, while getting data from database. Is there any way to delete empty rows in database?

```
<? 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 50");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $title = str_replace('-',' ',$row['tag']);
        if (strlen($title) > 50)
            $title = substr($title, 0, strrpos(substr($title, 0, 50), ' ')) . '...';
            $title = str_replace('---','-',$title);
            $title = str_replace('--','-',$title);
            $tag = str_replace('---','-',$row['tag']);
            $tag = str_replace('--','-',$tag);
        echo "<a href=/mp3/".UrlText($tag)."/ title=\"".$title."\">".$title . "</a> :: "; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: You mean there are rows in db with empty `tag` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To physically remove rows with empty (NULL) `tag` field use this query:

```
DELETE FROM tags WHERE tag IS NULL OR tag = '';
```

If you want to keep this rows but don't want to include it to query set use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tags 
WHERE tag IS NOT NULL AND tag != ''
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag IS NOT NULL  ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 30");

Comment: Yes it is correct, rows with empty `tag` field will be omitted.

Comment: how to delete automatically while retrieving data's

Comment: Then you need to execute 2 different query:
`DELETE FROM tags WHERE tag IS NULL;`
and 
`SELECT * FROM tags ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 30`

Comment: and it is not working, it gets data with empty row also, is there any option

Comment: What contents this rows - NULL or empty string? If empty string you should to alter WHERE clause to `tag !=''`

Comment: $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tags WHERE tag IS NULL AND SELECT * FROM tags ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 30"); is it correct

Comment: You should to use mysql_query function twice:

mysql_query("DELETE FROM tags WHERE tag IS NULL");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 30");

Comment: I've edited the answer to cover both variants of empty fields: when it equals to NULL and when it equals to ''(empty string).

Answer (score 1):

You can first delete the rows with null and then retrieve data from the db. And if you want the last 50 rows then why are you using limit 30?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tags ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 50 AS result) a WHERE a.result IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Please edit your post and explain why this would work.